# There is an error in my java coding when I put a grade percentage for my gradebook application

Tags: java

I have an application that acts as a gradebook. However, in the console log when I type in a grade there seems to be an error. I was hoping someone could fix this to where I am able to put in a grade percentage and the error does not pop up.`enter code here`

Below is what the error says:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "70%"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Gradebook.getScores(Gradebook.java:45)
at Gradebook.main(Gradebook.java:154)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gradebook {
    //getNumStudents takes a Scanner object as parameter
    //the reader object lets us take user input
    public static int getNumStudents(Scanner reader){
        int numStudents = 0;
        //we get the number of students
        do{
           System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");
           numStudents = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
           //we determine if the user input is valid
           //it should be greater than 0
           //because we don't want the number o students to be negative
           //if it is not valid then we keep taking inputs
           if(numStudents > 0){
               break;
           }else{
               System.out.println("Please enter atleast 1 student.");
           }
        }while(true);
        System.out.println("================================================================================================================================================");
        //we return numStudents
        return numStudents;
    }
    //getScores takes our Scanner object again and the number student as parameter this time
    public static String[] getScores(Scanner reader, int numStudents){
        //we create an array of string studInfo
        //that will be returned containing the name, and scores of our students
        String[] studInfo = new String[numStudents];
        String name = "";
        int quiz = 0;
        int assign = 0;
        int test1 = 0;
        int test2 = 0;
        //we use a for loop to keep taking student scores
        for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++){
            //enter name
            System.out.print("Enter student "+(i+1)+" name: ");
            name = reader.nextLine();
            //enter quiz, assignment, test1 and test2 scores
            //we also validate scores to not be negative
            //and not out of bounds
            do{
                System.out.print("Enter Quiz Score (over 40): ");
                quiz = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
                if(quiz >= 0 && quiz <= 40){
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Please put a valid score.");
                }
            }while(true);
            do{
                System.out.print("Enter Assignment Score (over 30): ");
                assign = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
                if(assign >= 0 && assign <= 30){
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Please put a valid score.");
                }
            }while(true);
            do{
                System.out.print("Enter Midterm Test Score (over 55): ");
                test1 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
                if(test1 >= 0 && test1 <= 55){
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Please put a valid score.");
                }
            }while(true);
            do{
                System.out.print("Enter Final Test Score (over 65): ");
                test2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
                if(test2 >= 0 && test2 <= 65){
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Please put a valid score.");
                }
            }while(true);  
            //after we get the name and student's score
            //we put it in a string 
            studInfo[i] = name+ " " +quiz+ " " +assign+ " " +test1+ " " +test2;
            System.out.println();
        }
        //return the studInfo
        return studInfo;
    }
    //our displayGrade takes String array as parameter
    public static void displayGrade(String[] studInfo){
        //this is our header for our formatted table
        System.out.println("================================================================================================================================================");
        System.out.println(String.format("%-30s%-10s%-12s%-15s%-12s%-10s%-15s%s", "Name", "Quiz", "Assignment", "Midterm Test", "Final Test", "Average", "Letter Grade", "Status"));
        System.out.println("================================================================================================================================================");
        //we go through our array of string
        for(int i = 0; i < studInfo.length; i++){
            //the split method returns an array of strings
            //that are split by a delimeter
            String[] data = studInfo[i].split(" ");
            //we sum up the scores
            //but we have to parse it to double first
            //to get the closest sum
            double sum = ((Double.parseDouble(data[1]) / 40.0) * 100.0) * 0.15;
            sum += ((Double.parseDouble(data[2]) / 30.0) * 100.0) * 0.15;
            sum += ((Double.parseDouble(data[3]) / 55.0) * 100.0) * 0.3;
            sum += ((Double.parseDouble(data[4]) / 65.0) * 100.0) * 0.4;
            //after that we round the sum and convert it to int and put it in average
            int average = (int) Math.round(sum);
            char letterGrade = ' ';
            //we get the letter grade using a nested if else
            if(average>=0 && average<=59){
                letterGrade = 'F';
            }else if(average>=60 && average<=69){
                letterGrade = 'D';
            }else if(average>=70 && average<=79){
                letterGrade = 'C';
            }else if(average>=80 && average<=89){
               letterGrade = 'B';
            }else if(average>=90 && average<=100){
                letterGrade = 'A';
            }
            String status = "";
            //we determine the status of our student here
            //using switch case 
            //if the leter grade is f then he fails
            //if the case is D then he needs to go to remedial class
            //otherwise they pass
            switch(letterGrade){
                case 'F':
                    status = "Fail";
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    status = "Remedial";
                    break;
                case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
                    status = "Pass";
                    break;
            }
            //we displat student information
            System.out.println(String.format("%-30s%-10s%-12s%-15s%-12s%-10d%-15c%s", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], average, letterGrade, status));
        }
        System.out.println("================================================================================================================================================");
     
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        displayGrade(getScores(reader, getNumStudents(reader)));
    }    
}
```

Comment: NumberFormatException shows up when you have non-digit character and are trying to parse it into a Number. In your case "%" is the culprit. Can you try with just entering "70" instead of "70%"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `nextLine()` you can use `next("[0-9]+%?")` and then remove the optional `%` character:

```java
public static int getNumStudents(Scanner reader) {

    int numStudents = 0;

    //we get the number of students

    do {

       System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");

       // Read the number either with or without the % sign
       String input = reader.next("[0-9]+%?");
       if (input.endsWith("%")) {
           // Remove the % sign if present
           input = input.substring(0, input.length() - 1); 
       }
       numStudents = Integer.parseInt(input);

       // we determine if the user input is valid
       // it should be greater than 0
       // because we don't want the number o students to be negative
       // if it is not valid then we keep taking inputs

       if (numStudents > 0) {
           break;
       }

       System.out.println("Please enter at least 1 student.");
    
    } while (true);

    System.out.println("================================================================================================================================================");

    // we return numStudents
    return numStudents;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind copying my code and then putting it in the changes and commenting. I am not really understanding how it is supposed to be changed.

Comment: @YusufKhan Please mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your problem.